# C#: Converting from Linq.Binary to Type in String

Tags: c#

I have a Linq.Binary object and I would like to convert it to the type contained within a string.

```
System.Data.Linq.Binary b = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(10.1);
string Type = "System.Double";

double d = Something(b, Type);
```

How do I convert from Linq.Binary to "System.Double" or "System.String"?  Do I just have to have a giant case statement or is their a slicker way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the byte[] into a BinaryReader and then you can extract the data out of it with the various Read methods.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf6bat53.aspx